# Files Can't transfer from Brackets to VS Code (HTML)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, adobe-brackets

I've been building a webite in Brackets, which is what I learned web development with. I decided to make the switch to VS Code, but when I dragged my folder over it didn't work. I was expecting to have my code just appear, but instead it says "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?"

Then, if I click yes, it gives me a long line of cryptic digits that look like question marks inside of hexagons.

Please let me know what I can do to tranfer over my files. Apologies if this is a simple answer, I'm very much a beginner here.

Comment: Is the file an image or some other non-text file?

Comment: try renaming the file type in your file explorer to .html if it isn't already. or try opening in notepad to see what each file looks like.

Comment: try right clicking on the folder and open with vscode option

Comment: @HereticMonkey I do have a subsidiary folder for images, but even for non-image pages it won't open properly

Comment: Impossible to say. It shows that dialog when you try to open a file that's not text. I would say you'd be better off using VSCode's Open Folder... dialog and opening the folder you're using with Brackets.

Comment: I don't have the option to do that. I'm on macbook.

Comment: Use **File** | **Open Folder**. Don't drag/drop folders